# condition for transitivity

Tags: relations

In transitive relations, $aRb$ and $bRc$ implies $aRc$. But what if there are no $bRc$, can we say that the relation is transitive?

For example, are relations $R\subseteq V\times V$, corresponding to graphs like this one, transitive?
$\require{AMScd}$
$$
\begin{CD}
\bullet @>>> \bullet@<<<\bullet\\
@VVV @AAA @VVV\\
\bullet @<<< \bullet@>>> \bullet\\
@AAA @VVV @AAA\\
\bullet @>>> \bullet@<<<\bullet
\end{CD}
$$

Answer (score 1):

A relation can be *trivially* transitive, so yes.

The condition for transitivity is:

Whenever $aRb$ and $bRc$ $-$ then it must be true that $aRc$.

That is, the only time a relation is not transitive is when $\exists  \; a,b,c$ with $aRb$ and $bRc$, but $aRc$ does not hold.

So the relation corresponding to the graph is trivially transitive.

You can learn a lot [about transitivity here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brelations%5Dtransitivity)